# JMeter - How to assert after the loop has finished

Tags: jmeter, assert

I am creating a JMeter test plan in which I need to execute several times the same request. For each request execution, I have a beanshell script that does some specific logic and increments a counter in a specific situation. 
The problem is that when I add a beanshell assert to check if the value is according I expect, this assertion does not wait for the loop to finish, and executes before.

Any idea on how can I make JMeter executes an assertion only after the loop has finished?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter assertions obey [JMeter scoping rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide), they are applied to the sampler(s) which are in their scope.

[image]

So if you want the assertion to be executed **after** the loop finishes - you need to add another sampler which will be doing nothing, i.e. [Dummy Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/DummySampler/) and add your final assertion as a child of this sampler.

[image]

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so make sure to migrate from Beanshell on next available opportunity